# Solaris IPS: pkg dependency errors bear no relation to actual issue / how best to diagnose IPS dependency failures?

Tags: solaris, solaris-11, ips

I am running Solaris 11.3 (at present from the non-contract Release repo).  I have a large amount of Solaris 10 experience, but I am newer to 11 and am still working on getting confident with IPS.

My issue is that I regularly find I have severe problems diagnosing package dependency failures, because the output of `pkg install` seems to bear no relation to the actual problem.  In fact I am now wondering if this is being caused by some bug or repository problem, as I'll explain at the end.

Below are two examples of recent problems I have faced where the output of a failed `pkg` command seems entirely unrelated to the real problem.  In the first example this caused me to spend literally days chasing red herrings until I eventually stumbled upon the required fix.

The global version is Oracle Solaris 11.3.1.5.1 (`pkg/entire` version `0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.1`.)   The global was installed from the USB text installer and since then I have version-unlocked and updated all the FOSS packages that were installed in the global by default (as per the [Oracle docs here](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-917308)), and additionally installed a few extra support packages (`vim`, `screen`, `tmux`, etc.)

When writing this post I re-created both examples from the position of a freshly installed `solaris-small-server` zone, with no other changes; the FOSS updates I describe above have occurred only in the global, not in the zone used to re-run the following examples and capture the error output.  The commands listed below are literally the first commands run in a test zone after it was created from the default zone AI manifest.

**Example 1**: I have been trying to install a working Gnome desktop in a non-global zone, without having to install packages in my global which I always want to keep lean and clean.

1. `zlogin zone pkg install --accept -v solaris-desktop` : fails because `driver/audio/audio-usb` says it must also be installed in the global zone.
2. I create a custom version of `solaris-desktop` called `solaris-desktop-zone` which removes all `driver/*` packages, and also any package that has dependency on the global (which I removed via a script that called `pkg contents -mr` on each package and removed any that referenced `feature/package/dependency/self`.)  I install this to my local repo, which is a `pkg/mirror` clone of `http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/`.
3. Installing my modified package results in the long list of dependency failures shown [in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/yrLR4XxZ), which are seemingly mostly related to Python packages.
4. I spent literally a day working through these errors: manually and recursively analysing the various Python packages and their dependencies and removing any mention that of them that I could find in my `solaris-desktop-zone` package.  Eventually I resorted to just removing packages in clumps until I found a version that would pass the Solver stage, and then worked backwards from there to identify the one package and finally understand the cause.

The solution?  `x11/server/xorg/driver/xorg-video` which depends on an NVidia driver which also has the `feature/package/dependency/self` dependency.  With hindsight I could have found this a lot quicker with a recursive search for that self dependency - ie check not only all the packages depended on by my `solaris-desktop-zone` package, but also all *their* dependencies.   But of course I was caught in a grind, believing from the errors that the problem was to do with Python packages or packages dependent on them.

**Example 2**: `gcc-5`

`zlogin testdesktop pkg install --accept -nv gcc-5` produces [this output](https://pastebin.com/raw/3NE7MJiv).

Again the same list of strange Python errors, and again the solution is entirely unrelated: I need to unlock some versions related to GCC:

```
pkg change-facet version-lock.system/library/gcc/gcc-c-runtime=false \
version-lock.system/library/gcc/gcc-c++-runtime=false \
version-lock.system/library/gcc/gcc-gfortran-runtime=false \
version-lock.system/library/gcc/gcc-gobjc-runtime=false
```

This one I thankfully found quickly via Google ([here on Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339296/where-is-gcc-5-after-installing-it-on-solaris-11/340163)).  But I was still left bemused because the diagnosis described by the person who answered it didn't match what I had seen  - the pkg errors listed in his post gave an understandable description of the problem (`Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation..`).    Mine has these unrelated Python errors again!

Now as I write this out I'm wondering if there's something weird going on at the moment in the Solaris 11.3 release repo, perhaps fixed by a SRU that I can't access until I get a contract.  Maybe that's why I am getting these weird errors rather than understandable, debuggable ones?

In that regard I do note there might be something wrong related to Dbus Python - one of the errors I see in both examples relates to `python-dbus-27`, which I note is now an obsoleted package which contains only a dependency on `dbus-python-27`.  But `dbus-python-27` does not exist in the repo.   So that might be a repo problem.

But even if so, why do I only see these errors when I have some other, completely unrelated problem?  Is that a bug caused by a repo problem?

I would be grateful for confirmation as to whether that's the case, and in general to learn more about the suggested methods and tools for debugging and resolving package dependency problems.  Given the errors I got, could I have resolved this quicker without resorting to brute-force checking of every dependent package?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some configurations require installation of packages into the global zone if they are installed in the non-global zone.  This is done by using 'parent' dependencies as I mentioned in another reply to you: [Solaris 11.3 non-global zones not inheriting IPS facet changes (to version-lock)](https://serverfault.com/questions/853789/solaris-11-3-non-global-zones-not-inheriting-ips-facet-changes-to-version-lock/854774#854774)

This is generally true for the dependencies of the solaris-desktop package because it relies on services that only the global zone can run (since only the global zone has an actual kernel), such as drivers, NFS, or other specific services.

The 'no version' 'can be found' errors are fairly literal; it basically means that no version that satisfies the package dependency is in the configure repository.

Unfortunately, it looks like you've discovered a problem with some of the evaluation packages.  You're not doing anything wrong, it just won't work right now.  This is something that will have to be fixed internally first.

I don't think anyone has tested the combination of the base 11.3 release with the evaluation packages and attempted to install 'solaris-desktop' at the same time.  This will take some time to resolve, so please be patient.

In the meantime, if you want a desktop-configured system, your best option is to *not* attempt to use the evaluation packages and to install solaris-desktop in the global zone first, and then the non-global zone.  That is by far the simplest option.

The only way around this at the moment would be to modify and republish the packages that are giving you problems, but I cannot guide you through that process at the moment.  Suffice to say, it would involve using pkgrecv --raw on each package you want to modify, then using pkgsend to republish each one to your own local repository.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks again for a good response.  OK, I'm glad to hear that a bug is confirmed - well, not glad, but at least it's not something on my end!  And yeah no worries about modifying packages, I do already have a working solaris-desktop in a non-global zone - without requiring it installed in the global.   I just need to remove `driver/*` packages and also `xorg-video`.   I've got the issue resolved, I just didn't understand these weird error messages that were unrelated to what I was doing.

Comment: Also, regarding the bug - as per Example 2, the issue with these errors on Python packages is not only related to solaris-desktop, and seemingly also not related to FOSS.   In Example 2 I am simply installing gcc-5 in a non-global zone installed with unmodified solaris-small-server.  No FOSS packages are in that non-global, nor is solaris-desktop.   So I am seemingly getting these errors related to Python packages in several error conditions, not just related to FOSS or olaris-desktop.   Unless it is related to FOSS installed in the **Global** - (contd..)

Comment: ie can having FOSS installed in my global cause the installation of `gcc-5` in a (non-FOSS) non-global zone to show these unrelated Python errors?  To be clear:  1. Global has all FOSS packages unlocked.  2. I install a non-global from `solaris-small-server` (no FOSS in the non-global) 3. zlogin zone pkg install gcc-5  =  shows the unrelated Python errors, where the true problem is I haven't done pkg facet version-lock for GCC.   So this is not related to solaris-desktop and seemingly not to FOSS, **unless* FOSS in the global is having an impact on the non-global despite no FOSS in non-global?

Comment: Finally (sorry for all the messages - very limited space here) -  to add to my first comment, I do have solaris-desktop in a non-global without needing it in the global.  However this only works if the non-global does not have FOSS updates.  If the non-global *does* have FOSS updates, I can still get it installed, but gdm won't start due to various dependency issues, which can be fixed, but ultimately XVnc just gives a green screen (same with `vncserver &`).  I've not bothered diagnosing that yet, I'm just running solaris-desktop in a non-FOSS zone which is fine.

Comment: The Image Packaging System evaluates all packages every time an operation is performed, so when you attempt an operation such as installing a package, it will show you all of the possible errors that would result from the proposed operation -- not just errors for the packages you are attempting to install. The entire dependency graph of the system is evaluated for every operation.

The FOSS evaluation packages cause some packages to be moved forward that affect the desktop packages and their dependencies, that's why you're encountering this difficulty.

Comment: The ability to install the solaris-desktop package is determined by whether its dependencies are satisfied.  So if all dependencies can be satisfied, you can install it.  If it doesn't work in one case, but does work in another, it is because dependencies cannot be satisfied either due to the installed set of packages or because of configuration.